# Curved normal random variable and conjugate prior

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, bayesian, bayes-theorem

**BACKGROUND:** Suppose the likelihood follows a Gaussian distribution, that is $X | \mu, \sigma \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$. Depending on which parameters are known (i.e. only $\mu$ is unknown; only $\sigma$ is unknown; and both $\mu, \sigma$ are unknown), we have appropriate conjugate priors such that the posterior distribution is also nicely behaved. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions for details.

**QUESTION:** But what if we have a *curved Gaussian distribution* (or more generally, a *curved exponential family*)? That is, what if $X | \mu \sim N(\mu, \mu)$ (i.e. $E[X|\mu] = \mu$, and $Var(X|\mu) = \mu^2$ )? What prior distribution for $\mu$ would lead to a nice distribution for the posterior $\mu | X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I think this is going to be hard to say much in the general case, but when looking for conjugate priors lets first indicate the strategy with a popular example and then try your case

#### Finding a Conjugate Prior; the Gaussian precision

So in this instance the likelihood given a collection of observations is 
$$
p(\mathbf{x}|\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathcal{N}(x_n | \mu, \lambda^{-1} ) \propto \lambda^{N/2} \exp\left\{ -\frac{\lambda}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_n-\mu)^2 \right\}
$$
Now we take that final term and write it in the form $f(\lambda)g(\lambda)$ where
\begin{align}
f(\lambda) &= \lambda^{N/2} \\
g(\lambda) &= \exp\left\{-\frac{\lambda}{2}\sum(x_n - \mu)^2 \right\}.
\end{align}
Now the step for constructing a conjugate prior $\pi(\lambda)$ is to chose its functional form such that 
$$
p(\mathbf{x}|\lambda)\pi(\lambda) \propto\tilde{f}(\lambda) \tilde{g}(\lambda)
$$
where $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ are of the same function class as $f$ and $g$ respectively. This leads us to to consider a prior of the form 
$$
\pi (\lambda) \propto \lambda^c e^{a\lambda + b}
$$
which after some normalisation we recognise as implying a Gamma distribution.

#### Curved Normal $\mathcal{N}\left(x | \mu, \mu\right)$

Using the same kind of strategy as above we have
$$
p(\mathbf{x} | \mu) \propto \frac{1}{\mu^{\frac{1}{2}}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\mu + \frac{\sum_i x_i^2}{\mu} - 2\sum_i x_i\right) \right\}
$$
this suggests a good prior may be of the form
$$
\pi(\mu) \propto \frac{1}{\mu^{r+1}}\exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2}\left(a_0\mu + \frac{b_0}{\mu} + 2c_0\right)\right\}
$$
the $c_0$ term is just going to get rolled into the normalising constant, indeed we find
$$
Z_{\pi} := e^{-c_0}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\mu^{r_0+1}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(a_0\mu + \frac{b_0}{\mu} \right)}d\mu = 2e^{-c_0} \frac{\sqrt{a_0b_0}}{b_0}^{r_0} K_{r_0}(\sqrt{a_0 b_0})
$$
where $K_r(\cdot)$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind. *Since we are getting a clean closed form expression it would not be surprising if this example has been covered somewhere in the literature!*

Finally then you get a posterior of the form
$$
p(\mu | x ) \propto \frac{1}{\mu^{r + 1}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left( a\mu + \frac{b}{\mu} - 2c \right) \right\}, \qquad \mu > 0,
$$
where the posterior parameters are 
\begin{align*}
r &= r_0 + \frac{1}{2} \\
a &= a_0 + 1 \\
b &= b_0 + \sum_i x_i^2 \\
c &= c_0 + \sum_i x_i
\end{align*}
and the normalising constant is
$$
Z_{\mu|x} = 2e^{-\sum_i x_i} \cdot \left( \frac{\sqrt{ab}}{b} \right)^{r}K_{r}(\sqrt{ab}).
$$

For general curved exponential distributions I don't know how much can be said beyond examining specific cases. Having thought about it for a bit one would think it should be possible to take the conjugate prior for the full exponential family of interest and then apply the same parameter restriction - where I can see this getting harder is if enforcing these parameter constraints lead to awkward expressions for the hyper parameters of the prior.

I guess a reasonable place to start would be to see if the Gaussian-Gamma distribution which is the conjugate prior to the $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution contains this distribution as a special subclass, in particular does the same parameter constraint $\mu = \sigma^2$ lead to the prior found above.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'd definitely Googled around before posting this question here, thinking that there must have some researchers who had thought of this generalization of conjugate priors for curved normal (exponential family) random variables. Perhaps the answer is too direct (well, definitely not for me!) and so nobody wrote a paper on it, or it's something overlooked in the literature? You seem fit to write a paper on this!